# Pip subprocess exits with an error when installing Kivy from Windows cmd.exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pip, kivy

Here is the full error:

```
C:\Windows\System32>pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (23.3.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (68.2.2)

C:\Windows\System32>pip install kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3

C:\Windows\System32>pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
Collecting kivy_examples
  Using cached https://kivy.org/downloads/ci/win/kivy/Kivy_examples-2.3.0.dev0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10.1 MB)
Collecting kivy[base]
  Using cached Kivy-2.2.1.tar.gz (24.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [11 lines of output]
      Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-68.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.41.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
      Collecting packaging
        Using cached packaging-23.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
      Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.33,>=0.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.33-py2.py3-none-any.whl (987 kB)
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
```

I actually first tried installing the kivy package using the `pip` command, `install kivy` but the same error occured.

Then I did what I did above, that is downloading it from the source:
`pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url`, but it still reported the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Python3.12, but Kivy only supports up to Python 3.11, per the [Kivy docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html):

> Kivy 2.2.1 officially supports Python versions 3.7 - 3.11.

The packages that are failing to install are not available for Python3.12 yet.